# Replace expression with function call in Python

Tags: python

## Context and Verbiage

Hello, I would like to share with you all a problem I spent all weekend working on.

If you are running a customized Python interpreter, you may need a way to capture the value of expressions - that is, values that are not assigned to any variable, like `x**2`, but unlike `y = x**2`. I won't get into the specifics, but one possibility is to replace the compiler with a function which parses the command as an [abstract syntax tree](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html), and substitutes in a function of your choosing, with the original expression as an argument.

## Actual Question

If I have a line of Python code I know to be complete, how do I reliably replace any un-captured expressions in it (`x**2` but not `y = x**2`) with a function call (*i.e.* `record(x**2)`)?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem revolves around [abstract syntax trees](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html). They can be used to describe Python code in a programmatic way. For example, when parsed via `ast.parse()`, we can see that expressions such as `x**2` are represented as `asp.Expr` objects.

Once you have obtained a tree object with `ast.parse()`, you can define a class and function to crawl the tree, and perform modifications. For example, this piece of code will replace every uncaptured expression with a method call `__recorder__.record()` using that expression as a parameter.

```
class CaptureExprs(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Expr(self, node):
        newnode = ast.copy_location(
            ast.Expr(
                value=ast.Call(
                    func=ast.Attribute(
                        value=ast.Name(
                            id='__recorder__',
                            ctx=ast.Load()
                        ),
                        attr="record",
                        ctx=ast.Load()
                    ),
                    args=[node.value],
                    keywords=[],
                    starargs=None,
                    kwargs=None
                )
            ),
            node
        )
        ast.fix_missing_locations(newnode)
        return newnode
```

Comment: You meant to answer your own question?

Comment: @user2963623: you may be interested in reading ["It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)